# Как создать скелетон-структуру при загрузке сайта?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Коллеги, добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста кто сталкивался с задачей создать скелетон-структуру при загрузке сайта (например как на youtube) ? можете посоветовать библиотеку с которой вы работали ? нашел одно решение на чистом css , но сейчас рассматриваю альтернативные варианты . Заранее спасибо )
[image: пример]

Comment: это называется `lazy-load` поищи инфу в гугле, ее предостаточно

Comment: @AndreyFreiz, не думаю, что это так называется. Точнее, так называется не это. Он спрашивает, как сверстать саму заглушку, показываемую во время загрузки данных.